# How to give random dyes in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to give the player a random dye when a player steps on a [command block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_block).
For eg

```
/give @p dye
```

gives the player only the Ink Sac dye but I want to give a random dye to the player.

Optional: Better if it requires only one command block.
Also helps if I can extend it to heads(`/give @p skull`).

Comment: Have you do anything to try and figure this out yourself? This question shows zero effort to try and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First summon some armor stand(depends on amount of dyes) with tag which equals dye name. Examples:

```
/summon armor_stand x y z {Tags:["red","dye"]}

/summon armor_stand x y z {Tags:["blue","dye"]}

/summon armor_stand x y z {Tags:["green","dye"]}
```

etc

Than checking a command block under player:
Repeating chain:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=rdye] remove rdye

/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ command_block -1 /scoreboard players
tag @a[tag=!rdye] add rdye

/execute @a[tag=rdye] ~ ~ ~ /exeute @r[type=armor_stand,tag=dye] ~ ~ ~
/setblock ~ ~-1 ~ stone
```

Next duplicate this command for each armor stand with tag

```
/execute @e[tag=red] ~ ~ ~ decetc ~ ~ ~ stone 0 /give @a[tag=rdye] dye
1 1
```

```
/execute @e[tag=blue] ~ ~ ~ decetc ~ ~ ~ stone 0 /give @a[tag=rdye]
dye 1 4
```

```
/execute @e[tag=green] ~ ~ ~ decetc ~ ~ ~ stone 0 /give @a[tag=rdye]
dye 1 2
```

etc

```
/execute @e[tag=dye] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt
```

it can be any block (instead of `dirt`).

I know that there are many methods, but I think it is more easy than methods with droppers or item rotation etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a random entity and base the `/give` command off of the result.

Initialization:
`/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random0,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random1,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random2,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random3,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random4,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random5,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random6,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random7,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random8,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random9,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random10,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random11,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random12,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random13,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random14,Tags:[random]}
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:random15,Tags:[random]}`

Commands when on pressure plate:
`/scoreboard players tag @r[type=armor_stand,tag=random] add selected
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random1] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 0
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random1] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 1
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random2] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 2
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random3] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 3
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random4] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 4
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random5] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 5
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random6] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 6
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random7] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 7
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random8] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 8
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random9] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 9
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random10] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 10
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random11] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 11
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random12] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 12
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random13] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 13
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random14] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 14
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=selected,name=random15] ~ ~ ~ give @p dye 1 15`

You have to replace `@p` with a selector that targets the player that you want to give the item to, of course.

Comment: (@r is the random selector here.)